# To make the following code run faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Consider the code:

where i read an input file with 6columns (0-5)

1. Initialize a variable historyends to 5000.
2. Next when the column0 value i,e job[0] < 5000 i add 5000lines of the input file in a list(historyjobs) else the rest of the lines till the eof in another list(targetjobs).
3. Next all the historyjobs list all contents in item3,item4,item5 is equal to targetjobs first list item3,item4,item5 when this condition is satisfied add those historyjobs all item1 to list listsub.
4. Next find the running mean of the items in listsub & reverse the list,store it in list a.Check the condition if items in listsub > a*0.9 the which staisfies the condition stores the result items in list condsub.
5. Next reopen the inputfile & check whether column0 is equal to items in condsub if it satisfies then add the column1 to a list condrun.
6. Finally open the output file & write in colum0 the second item of first list in targetjobs i,e j,in column1 write the average of list condrun,column2 is (j-avg)/j ,column3 is maximum item in list condrun ,column4 is minimum item in list condrun,column5 is length of list condrun,the last four column is based on condition.
7. Last i am repeating the whole procedure using a while loop by assigning the variable historyends to the next item int(targetjobs[1][0])

   ```
   from __future__ 
   import division
   import itertools   
   history_begins = 1; history_ends = 5000; n = 0; total = 0
   historyjobs = []; targetjobs = []
   listsub = []; listrun = []; listavg = [] ; F = [] ; condsub = [] ;condrun = [] ;mlistsub = []; a = []

   def check(inputfile):

     f = open(inputfile,'r') #reads the inputfile
     lines = f.readlines()
     for line in lines:
         job = line.split()
         if( int(job[0]) < history_ends ): #if the column0 is less then history_ends(i,e 5000 initially)
               historyjobs.append(job) #historyjobs list contains all the lines from the list whose column1 < history_ends
         else:
               targetjobs.append(job) #historyjobs list contains all the lines from the list whose column1 > history_ends  
     k = 0           
     for i, element in enumerate(historyjobs):
         if( (int(historyjobs[i][3]) == int(targetjobs[k][3])) and (int(historyjobs[i][4]) == int(targetjobs[k][4])) and (int(historyjobs[i][5]) == int(targetjobs[k][5])) ): #historyjobs list all contents in column3,column4,column5 is equal to targetjobs first list column3,column4,column5

                listsub.append(historyjobs[i][1]) #when if condition true add those historyjobs column1 to list listsub

   def runningMean(iterable):
   """A generator, yielding a cumulative average of its input."""
     num = 0
     denom = 0
     for x in iterable:
   num += x
   denom += 1
   yield num / denom

   def newfun(results):
     results.reverse() # put them back in regular order
     for value, average in results:
   a.append(value)
     return a #to return the value   


   def runcheck(subseq):
     f = open('newfileinput','r') #again read the same inputfile
     lines = f.readlines()
     for line in lines:
         job = line.split()
         for i, element in enumerate(subseq):
        if(int(job[1]) == int(subseq[i])): # if the column1 value of the inputfile becomes equal to list obtained
             condrun.append(str(job[2])) #return the value of column2 which satisfies the if condition
     return condrun


   def listcreate(condrun,condsub):
    f1 = open('outputfile','a') #outputfile to append the result
    s = map(int,condrun)
    j = int(targetjobs[0][2])
    targetsub = int(targetjobs[0][1])
    if(condsub != []):
     try:
      convertsub = int(condsub[-1])
      a=sum(s)/len(s)
      c=max(s)
      d=min(s)
      e1=abs(j-a)
      er1=e1/j
      g=len(s)
      h=abs(convertsub-targetsub)
      f1.write(str(j))
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write(str(round(a,2)))
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write(str(round(er1,3)))
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write(str(c))
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write(str(d))
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write(str(g))
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write(str(h))
      f1.write('\t')
      f1.write("\t")
      if (float(er1) < 0.20):
        f1.write("good")
        f1.write("\t")
      else :
        f1.write("bad")
        f1.write("\t")
      if (float(er1) < 0.30):
        f1.write("good")
        f1.write("\t")
      else :
        f1.write("bad")
        f1.write("\t")
      if (float(er1) < 0.40):
        f1.write("good")
        f1.write("\t")
      else :
        f1.write("bad")
        f1.write("\t")
      if (float(er1) < 0.50):
        f1.write("good")
        f1.write("\n")
      else :
        f1.write("bad")
        f1.write("\n")
     except ZeroDivisionError :
      print 'dem 0'
    else:
      print '0'
      f1.close() 

   def new():
    global history_ends
    while 1: #To repeat the process untill the EOF(end of input file)

   check('newfileinput') #First function call
   if(len(targetjobs) != 1):
    history_ends = int(targetjobs[1][0]) #initialize historyends to targetjobs second lines first item
    mlistsub = map(int,listsub)
    results = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0] > 0.9 * x[1],
                  itertools.izip(reversed(mlistsub),
                         runningMean(reversed(mlistsub)))))#call runningmean function & check the condition
    condsub = newfun(results) #function to reverse back the result    
    condrun=runcheck(condsub) #functionto match & return the value
    listcreate(condrun,condsub) #function to write result to output file     
    del condrun[0:len(condrun)]#to delete the values in list
    del condsub[0:len(condsub)]#to delete the values in list
    del listsub[0:len(listsub)]#to delete the values in list
    del targetjobs[0:len(targetjobs)]#to delete the values in list
    del historyjobs[0:len(historyjobs)]#to delete the values in list
   else:
     break


   def main():      
      new()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
   ```

the sample input file(whole file contains 200,000 lines):

```
 1  0   9227    1152    34  2
 2  111 7622    1120    34  2
 3  68486   710 1024    14  2
 6  265065  3389    800 22  2
 7  393152  48438   64  132 3
 8  412251  46744   64  132 3
 9  430593  50866   256 95  4
 10 430730  10770   256 95  4
 11 433750  12701   256 14  3
 12 437926  2794    64  34  2
 13 440070  43  32  96  3
 13 440070  43  32  96  3
 14 440102  44  32  96  3
 15 440357  43  32  96  3
 16 440545  43  32  96  3
 17 440599  43  32  96  3
 18 440625  43  32  96  3
 19 440999  84  32  96  0
 20 441574  44  32  96  3
 21 442667  7914    512 14  3
 22 443249  45  32  96  3
 25 443797  3260    128 68  4
 26 443799  3746    128 68  4
 27 445357  31  8   29  3
 28 445393  31  8   29  3
 29 445445  28  8   29  3
 30 445488  29  8   29  3
```

the sample output file contents:

```
    930     1389.14     0.494       3625        977     7       15      bad bad bad good
    4348        1331.75     0.694       3625        930     8       164     bad bad bad bad
    18047       32237.0     0.786       61465       17285       3       325774      bad bad bad bad
    1607        1509.0      0.061       1509        1509        1       6508        good    good    good    good
    304     40.06       0.868       80      32      35      53472       bad bad bad bad
    7246        7247.0      0.0     7247        7247        1       9691        good    good    good    good
    95      1558.0      15.4        1607        1509        2       2148        bad bad bad bad
    55      54.33       0.012       56      53      3       448142      good    good    good    good
    31      76.38       1.464       392     35      13      237152      bad bad bad bad
    207     55.0        0.734       55      55      1       370     bad bad bad bad
```

if anyone could suggest some changes through which the code runs faster it would be helpful...

The input file:

```
  column 0-->represents jobnum
  column 1-->represents submittime
  column 2-->represents runtime
  column 3-->represents userid
  column 4-->represents numberof processor
  column 5-->represents queueid
```

I maintain the first 5000 lines in inputfile as some kind of history read the 5001th line compare whether its col3,col4,col5 value is equal to values in that 5000lines.if some 20 lines has the matching values then all those which satisfies the conditions col2 to a list.
find the running mean of this list & store the result to another list1.Now check the condition for all items (list1 > list*0.9) the items which satisfies the condition add it to another list list3. All the items in list3 which matches the col0 of 5000lines in history,store the col2 to list4.Now i need to open a file to write avg of the final list4.Repeat the same by incrementing the history to the next line until the EOF

Comment: The first step in making your code go faster is finding out which part is slowest.  `check()` and `listcreate()` look like good culprits, but nothing beats actual metrics.

Comment: might be better for codereview.stackexchange

Comment: Before jumping in to make the code faster please use the python's profiler facility to identify where the time is actually being spent in your program. Once you identify which function or block of code is the bottleneck, you will do a better job of optimizing it. Python contains a standard profile module to make this easier. You should perhaps look at this:http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-profile

Comment: check() & runcheck() are the bottlenecks but i am not knowing what changes to do

Comment: @JhonWatson I'd love to optimize your code but I find it difficult to follow the description of your implementation, could you make a resume of the requirements of the code in an EDIT at the end?

Comment: definitely profile your code. also, you seem to have many many write statements (e.g., write('\t') twice instead of write('\t\t')) etc .. how about building some of your output first locally and then writing in one or two swoops?

Comment: If you don't give an input file of limited size that could really be treated, or more understandable explanations , you will get no more help, because your question is like a queasy porridge.

Comment: A side note: the `f` in `check()` should also be closed.

Comment: Your import line, are you sure about that?

Comment: What value must we affect to ``historyends`` with the input you gave and updated ? There are now two identical lines numbered ``13``, is it the place where the separation between ``historyjobs`` and ``targetjobs`` must occur ?

Comment: Your comment of ``if( int(job[0]) < history_ends )`` is **....whose column1 < history_ends** , and your comment to ``listsub.append(historyjobs[i][1])`` is **...add those historyjobs' column1 #to list listsub** . Do you want to add ``historyjobs[i][1])`` or ``historyjobs[i][1])`` in ``listsub`` ??

Comment: In your updated input sample, there are two lines 13 440070 43 32 96 3. The fact that there are two lines with the same value 440070 in column 1 has a consequence during execution of runcheck. Is the presence of these two identical lines an error or not ?

Comment: According to yor code, the value of ``j`` is the first to be written in each line of the file of name ``outputfile`` with file-handler ``f1``. Since object **j** is defined with ``j = int(targetjobs[0][2])`` , the value of ``j`` must be one of  the values in column 3 of your input sample. However, none of the values appearing at first position on the lines of the output sample you give, except value ``31``, is present in column 3 of the input sample. I conclude that the output file doesn't correspond to the input sample. Please, be more serious in writing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following code does the same as yours:

```
from __future__ import division
from sys import exit
history_begins = 1
history_ends = 16
historyjobs = []
targetjobs = []

def quickzh(zhlistsub,
            historyjobs=historyjobs):
    rev = reversed(zhlistsub)
    i = next(rev)
    num   =  historyjobs[i][1]
    denom = 1
    hfirst  = num
    li = [historyjobs[i][2]]
    for i in rev:
        x = historyjobs[i][1]
        num += x
        denom += 1
        if x > 0.9 * (num / denom):
            li.append(historyjobs[i][2])
        else:
            break
    li.reverse()
    return hfirst,li 


def listcreate(hfirst,s,
               historyjobs=historyjobs,targetjobs=targetjobs):
    with open('outputfile.txt','a') as f1:
        j = targetjobs[0][2]
        try:
            a,c,d,g = sum(s)/len(s), max(s), min(s), len(s)
            e1  = abs(j-a)
            er1 = e1/j
            h   = abs(hfirst-targetjobs[0][1])
            # historyjobs[-1][1] is convertsub
            # targetjobs[0][1]   is targetsub
            f1.write('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t' %
                     (j, round(a,2), round(er1,3), c, d, g, h))
            f1.write("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" %
                     tuple("good" if er1 < x else "bad" for x in (0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5)))
        except ZeroDivisionError :
            print 'dem 0'
        else:
            print '0'
            f1.close()

def new(inputfile,history_ends,
        historyjobs=historyjobs,targetjobs=targetjobs):
    while 1:

        # checking the file
        with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                job = map(int,line.split())
                (historyjobs if job[0]  < history_ends
                 else targetjobs).append(job)  

        if len(targetjobs) != 1:
            k = 0           
            zhlistsub = [i for i, element in enumerate(historyjobs)
                         if element[3:6] == targetjobs[k][3:6] ]
            if zhlistsub:
                listcreate(*quickzh(zhlistsub))
            history_ends = targetjobs[1][0]
            del targetjobs[:]
            del historyjobs[:]
        else:
            break


new('toto.txt',history_ends)
```

With the input sample you gave and `history_ends = 16` , the ouput file becomes:

```
43  43.5    0.012   44  43  2   188 good    good    good    good
43  43.33   0.008   44  43  3   54  good    good    good    good
43  43.25   0.006   44  43  4   26  good    good    good    good
44  43.2    0.018   44  43  5   949 good    good    good    good
45  49.14   0.092   84  43  7   1675    good    good    good    good
3746    3260.0  0.13    3260    3260    1   2   good    good    good    good
31  31.0    0.0 31  31  1   36  good    good    good    good
28  31.0    0.107   31  31  2   52  good    good    good    good
```

If you need explanations, ask me.
The principle is to track tyhe indices, not the values in historyjobs.

Just a remark:
in the generator function `runningMean()`:

```
for x in iterable:
    num += x
    denom += 1
    yield num / denom
```

for the first element of the iterable, `denom` equals 1 then `num/denom` equals `num`.
Consequently, in the `takewhile(lambda x: x[0] > 0.9 * x[1],
                                     izip(reversed(mlistsub),
                                          runningMean(reversed(mlistsub)))))`
the first element `x` is always of the kind `(el,el)`, then `x[0] > 0.9 * x[1]` is always true for the first element, and then `results` and `consub` are never void list.
So in the `listcreate()` function, the argument `condsub` passed is never void and the condition `if consub != |]` is always true.
That's why in my code, this condition has disappeared.

.

#### EDIT

If the values of the first column of the inputfile, that are read as job[0], are increasing values, you can modify `new()` to:

```
def new(inputfile,history_ends,
        historyjobs=historyjobs,targetjobs=targetjobs):

    # checking the file
    with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            job = map(int,line.split())
            (historyjobs if job[0]  < history_ends
             else targetjobs).append(job)

    while True:
        k = 0           
        zhlistsub = [i for i, element in enumerate(historyjobs)
                     if element[3:6] == targetjobs[k][3:6] ]
        if zhlistsub:
            listcreate(*quickzh(zhlistsub))
        tj00 = targetjobs[0][0]
        while True:
            if targetjobs[0][0]!=tj00:
                break
            historyjobs.append(targetjobs.pop(0))
        if len(targetjobs)==0:
            break
```

If the values are strictly increasing, that is to say no two lines having the same value in column 1, I think you can simplify to:

```
def new(inputfile,history_ends,
        historyjobs=historyjobs,targetjobs=targetjobs):

    # checking the file
    with open(inputfile,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            job = map(int,line.split())
            (historyjobs if job[0]  < history_ends
             else targetjobs).append(job)

    while True:
        k = 0           
        zhlistsub = [i for i, element in enumerate(historyjobs)
                     if element[3:6] == targetjobs[k][3:6] ]
        if zhlistsub:
            listcreate(*quickzh(zhlistsub))
        historyjobs.append(targetjobs.pop(0))
        if len(targetjobs)==0:
            break
```

NB I still don't understand the need of `k`

Comment: @Jhon Watson I wonder what is the aim of ``k = 0`` but I kept it

Comment: thanks the code runs fast but only one problem with it is  h   = abs(historyjobs[-1][1]-targetjobs[0][1]) its not always to subtract the last of historyjobs.It is to obtain the historyjobs[0][1] whict satisfy the if x > 0.9 * (num / denom): & one more list ji.append(historyjobs[i][1]) & finally the h = abs(ji[-1][1]-targetjobs[0][1]) but i am not knowing how to retun both ji & li....

Comment: I've changed the function ``quickzh()``, the parameters of ``listcreate()``, and its call, to be adapted to this change. ``quickzh`` now determines the value of the first object needed to calculate ``h``. Say me if the results are correct with this.

Comment: You should click on the ``help`` button at the right of the writable window for comments: you would learn how to format the texts in the comments in order to make them more readable. For example this **word** is surrouned by two stars at its left and two stars at its right, and this ``one`` is surrounded by two `` on each of its side (not quotes, but reversed quotes).

Comment: @Jhon Watsonc Thank you. There's possibly an improvement to do, but it depends of the following characteristic: **if the values of the first column of the ``inputfile``, that are read as ``job[0]``, are increasing values**, then we are sure that the successive values of ``history_ends`` are increasing too. That's because by construct, ``history_ends<=targetjobs[0][0]`` is always True, then we are sure that ``history_ends<=targetjobs[1][0]``. So, when the instruction ``history_ends = targetjobs[1][0]`` is executed just before the draining of lists ``historyjobs`` and ``targetjobs``, it ......

Comment: @John Watson ...... makes the new value of ``history_ends`` greater than the former one. If really so, this can be used to simplify the code by checking the ``inputfile`` only once. Say me, please, if values of column 1 in the ``inputfile`` are increasing and I will modify my code. Even if not strictly increasing, it will be possible.

Comment: ya the value of column1 is increasing values.Actually i need to **first maintain history of 5000 jobs** so `history_ends = 5000` then the remaining to compare with that history of 5000 jobs one by one with the remaining jobs in the inputfile so    `k = 0`  .If their is any other easier way to do then plz suggest me........

Answer (score 3):

Both `check` and `runcheck` have this code that reads the entire file, then iterates over all the lines.  Replace the following:

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
```

with:

```
for line in f:
```

to only read and process the lines in one pass.